# Convert HTML_tables to character before stacking with other tables from a map_df loop

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to scrape data individual game stats by year from basketball-reference.com for Michael Jordan, but some of the years that he played come through as character only and some are a mix of char/integer, which cause failures in the map_df procedure.  I tried adding 'mutate_all(as.character)' to my code, but I think this is trying to convert the data to char after it has already been looped through by map_df.  I need a way to convert each individual iteration to char before stacking the results. I can just convert the numbers to int format after they have already been stacked.  Any insights are appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create tibbles for each player
#########################################################################

jordan <- tibble(
  player_name = 'Michael Jordan',
  player_id = 'jordami01',
  initial = 'j',
  year = 1985:2003)

# Create df of players to be scraped
#########################################################################

players = bind_rows(jordan)

urls <- sprintf("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/%s/%s/gamelog/%s", 
                players$initial, players$player_id, players$year)

# output[] <- lapply(output, as.character)
output <- purrr::map_df(urls, ~.x %>% 
                  read_html() %>%
                  html_nodes("#pgl_basic") %>% 
                  html_table() %>%
                  mutate_all(as.character))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of complications in this data to combine them into one dataframe.

1. Not all of the urls return table.
2. There are duplicate column names in table (R does not like that)
3. There are also columns with no name (R does not like that either)

I have renamed the column names to be `col1`, `col2` etc to avoid issue 2 and 3.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
  
map_df(urls, ~{
            .x %>% 
               read_html() %>%
              html_nodes("#pgl_basic") %>% 
              html_table() -> tmp
  if(length(tmp)) {
    tmp <- tmp[[1]]
    setNames(tmp, paste0('col', seq_along(tmp))) %>%
      mutate(across(.fns = as.character))
    }
  else NULL
}) -> result
```